# Are these triangles similar?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given only the information conveyed in the diagram (cannot assume any angle measure except the 2 right angles explicitly specified), are triangles AED and DFC similar? My thinking is they are not guaranteed to be similar because angles EBF and EDF are not necessarily 90 degrees. [image]

Comment: you're thinking is right

Comment: Suppose an arrangement in which the triangles $AED$ and $DFC$ are similar. Then pick point $B$ and drag it along $BC$. Angles of triangle $AED$ will change, angles of $DFC$ won't. Therefore the triangles won't be similar anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The six points highlighted in the photo can be parameterized as follows:

$$
A = (0,0),
\quad \quad \quad
B = \left(b\cos\alpha,\,b\sin\alpha\right),
\quad \quad \quad
C = \left(c,\,0\right),
$$

$$
D = A + (C-A)\,t,
\quad \quad \quad
E = A + (B-A)\,u,
\quad \quad \quad
F = B + (C-B)\,v,
$$

with $0 < \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}$, $b>0$, $c>0$, $0<t<1$, $0<u<1$, $0<v<1$.

So, imposing the two orthogonality conditions:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& (E-A)\cdot(E-D) = 0
\quad \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \quad
u = \frac{c\,t\cos\alpha}{b}\,; \\
& (F-C)\cdot(F-D) = 0
\quad \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \quad
v = \frac{b(b-c\cos\alpha)+c\,t(c-b\cos\alpha)}{b^2+c^2-2\,b\,c\cos\alpha}\,; \\
\end{aligned}
$$

it's possible to impose that the corresponding sides are in proportion:

$$
\frac{\overline{AD}}{\overline{DC}} = \frac{\overline{AE}}{\overline{DF}} = \frac{\overline{DE}}{\overline{CF}}
$$

which together with the conditions of existence of the six parameters leads to:

$$
b = c\cos\alpha, \quad \quad \text{with} \; 0 < \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}, \; c > 0, \; 0 < t < 1\,.
$$

So yes, you're right, only with this other condition can we be sure of the similarity.

Answer (score 1):

As given there is no similarity as per a construction with simple angle chasing around a cyclic quadrilateral.

This is because no angle coincidence in the right triangles.

This can happen only if the inscribed cyclic quadrilateral is a rectangle.

[image]